# Check which are the next layers in a tensorflow keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model which has shortcuts between layers. For each layer, I would like to get the name (or index) of the next connected layers, because simply iterating through all the `model.layers` will not tell me whether the layer was connected to the previous one or not.

An example model could be:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the information in `dict` format in this way...

Firstly, define a utility function and get the relevant nodes as made in the `model.summary()` method from every `Functional` model ([code reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L213))

```
relevant_nodes = []
for v in model._nodes_by_depth.values():
    relevant_nodes += v

def get_layer_summary_with_connections(layer):
    
    info = {}
    connections = []
    for node in layer._inbound_nodes:
        if relevant_nodes and node not in relevant_nodes:
            # node is not part of the current network
            continue

        for inbound_layer, node_index, tensor_index, _ in node.iterate_inbound():
            connections.append(inbound_layer.name)
            
    name = layer.name
    info['type'] = layer.__class__.__name__
    info['parents'] = connections
            
    return info
```

Secondly, extract the information iterating through layers:

```
results = {}
layers = model.layers
for layer in layers:
    info = get_layer_summary_with_connections(layer)
    results[layer.name] = info
```

`results` is a nested `dict` with this format:

```
{
  'layer_name': {'type':'the layer type', 'parents':'list of the parent layers'},
  ...
  'layer_name': {'type':'the layer type', 'parents':'list of the parent layers'}
}
```

For `ResNet50` it results in:

```
{
  'input_4': {'type': 'InputLayer', 'parents': []},
  'conv1_pad': {'type': 'ZeroPadding2D', 'parents': ['input_4']},
  'conv1_conv': {'type': 'Conv2D', 'parents': ['conv1_pad']},
  'conv1_bn': {'type': 'BatchNormalization', 'parents': ['conv1_conv']},
  ...
  'conv5_block3_out': {'type': 'Activation', 'parents': ['conv5_block3_add']},
  'avg_pool': {'type': 'GlobalAveragePooling2D', 'parents' ['conv5_block3_out']},
  'predictions': {'type': 'Dense', 'parents': ['avg_pool']}
}
```

Also, you can modify `get_layer_summary_with_connections` to return all the information you are interested in

Answer (score 2):

You can view the whole model and its connections with the keras's [Model plotting utilities](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/)

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='path/to/image', show_shapes=True)
```